# Teams DeepLink URL for Calling

Tags: android, ios, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

Given MS Teams client is installed on android/ios, I wonder if anyone knows how I can launch teams from a custom app and directly call someone?

1. for contacts in your org
2. external phone number

Apperciate it!

Comment: msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<email>

Comment: hi @udbhateja thanks! as I understand it, this is for chatting right? What if you want to call? And what if you want to call a direct phone number?

Comment: Currently MS Teams only support Chat and Schedule Meeting URL schemes, can't find any url schemes for calling. @Rafferty

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported. Please [vote](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/42990894-deep-link-to-a-one-2-one-call) for it to be added via this feature request.